# HashSet iterator remove never working for socket/thread class

Tags: java

I'm working on a basic client/server java app. Everything works fine, except that the my code to remove "dead" connections never actually removes them.

When a listener thread encounters an exception (broken pipe, etc) it sets a boolean that it's "dead", so that the next time the server thread runs, it scans for all connections marked "dead" and it should remove them so we don't try to write to them anymore.

The code below runs, and I see the log message - but the `.remove` never does anything. When I debug `pool.size()` both before and after this code block, it never decreases - only increases when new connections are established.

```
public static volatile HashSet<ClientListener> pool = new HashSet<ClientListener>(); 

Iterator<ClientListener> listeners = pool.iterator();
while( listeners.hasNext() ){
    ClientListener l = listeners.next();
    if( l.isDead() ){
        MyApp.log( "Removing dead/errored client listener..." + l.getIdentifier() + " " + l.listenerId );
        listeners.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As written, the code looks OK.   However, the fact that you have declared `pool` as to be `volatile` implies that the code is multi-threaded, and if another thread is adding new `ClientListener` objects to `pool`, then this code is not thread-safe.  That may be sufficient to cause anomalies that would explain the strange behaviour.

A simple fix would be to change

```
   HashSet<ClientListener>
```

to

```
   ConcurrentHashMap<ClientListener, ClientListener>
```

The other thing you could / should do is to compare what `pool.size()` says immediately before and after the `listener.remove()` call.

Finally, the `listener.remove()` call could be throwing an exception.  If you were squashing that exception further up the call stack, then that might explain why you can't figure out what is going on here.